# What will happen if in the Breadth-FirstSearch(BFS) algorithm a stack is used instead of queueq?

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

What will happen if in the Breadth-FirstSearch(BFS) algorithm a stack is used instead of queueq?

```
pseudocode of BFS with queue:
    BFS(node)
    {
       queue <- node
       while queue not empty 
       v <-- queue
       print v
       for each child c of v quequ <-c
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

in this case it becomes depth first search